# Delay on page redirect

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, redirect, delay, page-load-time

I have a web application built on Java Spring framework with a mysql database. It is hosted on a Linode with Ubuntu Lucid 10.04. I use the apache mod_rewrite for redirections. Everytime a page redirect is done, there is a delay before the next page is loaded. Once the other page starts rendering, the page is loaded quickly. The delay is after clicking on an ahref link, till the load of the next page. During this delay the bottom left of the browser shows 'waiting for doondoo'. This issue exists in general for the whole web application. I would like to know what is causing this delay? Is it the query on the page or the html components that need to be loaded or the redirect rules or is it something else? Any suggestions would be helpful to get to the root cause of the problem. To check the problem you can visit [www.doondoo.com](http://www.doondoo.com) and click on any link on the page. Thanks in advance.

I have now added a snapshot which shows a waiting time of 5.4s. Will using object level caching solve the problem?
[image: Delay Snapshot]

Comment: I'd suggest using Firebug or Page Speed to see exactly where the delay is (DNS, request, response, rendering, etc...)

Comment: @Beau Grantham I have added the snapshot which shows a waiting time of 5.4s but it doesn't exactly say what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maxim --

I use Chrome as my browser, and it has a very handy set of Developer Tools (under the "View" menu on a Mac, and somewhere similar under Windows) that include a timeline of network requests.   It's documented here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

I'm looking at your doondoo page from the U.S., and the resources that seem to be taking the longest to come in (and delaying the page rendering) are the company thumbails, all of which are saved as GIFs, some of them 40-50kB in size.  I tried grabbing one of them and resaving it as a JPEG, and it reduced down to around 11kB, so you may try reducing the size of those images. It looks like you're explicitly laying out the page's elements sizes in your CSS, which is good, and I would expect to see the page render much more quickly with smaller images.

I highly recommend either Firebug (in Firefox) or the Developer Tools in Chrome, either of which will help you further pinpoint what's taking so long to render.

Good luck!